# how to chop up returned string from file_get_contents() into variable

Tags: php, wordpress, forms

i have a wordpress plugin that sends a request using file_get_contents() to a url and in-turn receive an image and four variables which ofcoz are already processed so they are just four words. How to i break down this string (using php) so i can take turn the four words into variable again as soon as they are returned,  and use them on that page, (page C. )
    here is a diagram of what i want to do

http://itmastersworld.com/my_problem.jpg

I have tried placing a form to be part of the string returned but apparently there is no way of manupilating the data inside the form

```
 <form><input id="test" name="avariable" type="hidden" value="<?php echo $xxxx; ?>" /></form>
```

it works but i cant find a way to use the `value=""` without submiting the form from the server(using stuff like

```
$yes = $_REQUEST['avariable']
```

,) the form is introduced in part B that is, and appears in part c. 
Help ???? I basically need my php variable created in part B.!!

Comment: Make sure you wrap any data you insert into HTML with `htmlspecialchars()`.  Otherwise, you may be generating invalid HTML, and possible opening yourself up to XSS depending on where that data comes from.

Comment: the data is coming from my own server

Comment: Okay, the script in itself works and returns the image and some vairiables, just need to convert the 'variables' back to php so i can further use them on page c.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Since you already have control on the page B, you can send them with some delimiter and split them? For example lets say the output is

```
word1,,,word2,,,word3,,,word4
```

Your code can be

```
<?php
    $vars = explode(",,,", file_get_contents('your_url');
    // echo $vars[1];
    // echo $vars[2];
    // echo $vars[3];
    // echo $vars[4];
?>
```

Comment: the bottom part looks like this                                                                                    <?php echo $http_code. $new_url. $codes[$http_code]. $http_code;?>

<input id="yes" name="yes" type="text" value="<?php echo $codes[$http_code]; ?>" /></form>
<img src="xxxxx<?php echo $title;?> " />

Comment: and the biggest problem is that the returned string comes out in one go, so if i echo it for the middle part of the document it comes out it that exact order and i cant manupilate anywhere else to put it.

Comment: i cant exactly do this      $vars = explode(",,,", file_get_contents('your_url'); because the instructions to part b run an indenpendent process on the linux server which is responsnible for the image, hence the variables i am talking about are just some are "extra stuff i do" after the process has been run, wkhtmltoimage

Comment: @Mohammed Ameenudd please try this link and see what it bring back , you might get a better idea of how to help me http://itmastersworld.com/liveshot/getImage.php?url=http://bbc.com&title=shota.png&width=190&height=240&quality=70&zoom=0.3 takes about 10 sec to load

Comment: @Mohammed Ameenudd, hie , i got it to work using your instructions